# Find the index of supersets for each sublist in another list

Tags: python, list, indexing, set

I am trying to find the index number in a list of elements that share the same data with elements in another list. These are  my lists:

```
list_A = [['A',1,'a',],['B',2,'b'],['C',3,'c'],['D',4,'d'],['E',5,'e'],['F',6,'f']]
list_B = [['A','a'],['D','d']['E','e']]
```

And the desired output should be:

```
[0,3,4]
```

I've tried using the set()intersection and the the index functions, but I couldn't make 'set' work with the list of lists.

Comment: What is there is no match?

Comment: Your "edit" has invalidated every answer here because no indication was made about the presence of mutable types in the sublist.

Comment: I know - apologise. Should I delete it and open as a new question?

Comment: No, is disrespectful to the users here who have answered your question. By suggestion is to accept one of the answers here you felt best solved _this_ problem, and then open a new question which better enumerates your requirements. Does that sound good? :-)

Comment: Yep - will do so. (Sorry - I'm kind of new in this community and not familiar with its rules. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
list_A = [['A', 1, 'a', ], ['B', 2, 'b'], ['C', 3, 'c'], ['D', 4, 'd'], ['E', 5, 'e'], ['F', 6, 'f']]
list_B = [['A', 'a'], ['D', 'd'], ['E', 'e']]

set_B = list(map(set, list_B))
result = [i for i, e in enumerate(list_A) if any(b.intersection(e) for b in set_B)]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Do note that calling `set.intersection` is less efficient than calling `set.issuperset/issubset`, the latter returns a boolean value while the former builds and returns a set in memory.

Answer (score 4):

If your list values don't have duplicates, you can convert everything to a set and perform subset checks inside a list comprehension.

```
set_A = list(map(set, list_A))
set_B = list(map(set, list_B)) 
# set_B = map(set, list_B) # If you intend to use and throw. 

[next((i for i, a in enumerate(set_A) if a.issuperset(b)), None) for b in set_B]
# [0, 3, 4]
```

For now, if there is no match, `next` returns the default value you passed to it, in this case - `None`.

Comment: very good because it converts to set beforehand, avoiding the extra overhead

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Perhaps you meant that for set_B? that is iterated upon only once. But yes, you're right.