# Finding the index of entries in lists of lists, with duplication and sub-lists

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to find the index of elements that contain similar entries in lists of lists.
Data might contained duplicated entries as well as sub-lists.
For example:

```
list_A = [['A',[1],'a',],['B',[2],'b'],['C',[3],'c'],['D',[4],'d'],['E',[5],'e'],['A',[1],'a',]]
list_B = [['A','a'],['E','e']]
```

The desired output should be:

```
[0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What happens if b contains an element of the sublist of list_A for example: `list_A = ['A', [1]]` and `list_B = [[1]]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the index of supersets for each sublist in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53848902/find-the-index-of-supersets-for-each-sublist-in-another-list)

Comment: @Gsk I'm not entirely sure why this person has asked an almost identical question twice in 30 minutes when they had an answer the first time - should this question be marked as spam?

Comment: @Andrew I think that it is an edge case and no one will take a decision. I see in the comments of the other question that user coldspeed is suggesting to open a new question, because adding nested lists (i.e. `[1]`) completely invalidate his question. In my opinion these 2 question *are* duplicates, and if an edit of the OP invalidate an answer, that answer should be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the number shown at index 1, you can use:

```
res = []

for lb in list_B:
    for la in list_A:
        if all([x in la for x in lb]):
            res.append(la[1][0])

print sorted(res)

# OUTPUT: [1, 1, 5]
```

if you want the index in `list_A`, you should use:

```
res = []

for lb in list_B:
    for n, la in enumerate(list_A):
        if all([x in la for x in lb]):
            res.append(n)

print sorted(res)

# OUTPUT: [0, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools

list_A = [['A',[1],'a',],['B',[2],'b'],['C',[3],'c'],['D',[4],'d'],['E',[5],'e'],['A',[1],'a',]]
list_B = [['A','a'],['E','e']]

desired_output = []
for i,j in itertools.product(enumerate(list_A),list_B):
     if all(k in i[1] for k in j):
         desired_output.append(i[0])
```

output:

```
[0, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you eliminate the inner lists from each element in list_A, you can compare the elements directly with list_B:

```
list_A = [['A',[1],'a'], ['B',[2],'b'], ['C',[3],'c'], ['D',[4],'d'], 
          ['E',[5],'e'], ['F',[6],'f']]
list_B = [['A','a'],['D','d'],['E','e']]

new_A = ([a, b] for a, _, b in list_A)
common = [i for i, x in enumerate(new_A) if x in list_B]
```

If you're sure that each element of list_B is uniquely present, then the following works too:

```
new_A = [[a, b] for a, _, b in list_A]
common = [new_A.index(x) for x in list_B]
```